# Ты последний человек(,) которого я буду ждать

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение

Лишняя ли запятая в предложении?
**Ты последний человек, которого я буду ждать.**

Comment: Это случайно не перевод с английского? Так очень редко говорят по-русски.

Answer (score 2):

Никоим образом запятая здесь не лишняя.
**Ты последний человек, которого я буду ждать.**

Смотрим в словаре Ожегова:
[**который**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/90842), -ая, -ое, *местоимение*
**2.** *союзн.* Связывает с главным предложением придаточное, определяющее какое-нибудь существительное главного предложения. *Город, в котором прошло детство.*

Перед словом *который* ставится запятая, если это относительное местоимение в позиции союзного слова (местоимения, которое выполняет функции союза: связывает части сложного предложения).
*Это был дом, который построили в прошлом году.*

[Запятая перед «который» нужна или нет?](https://obrazovaka.ru/zapyataya/kotoryy.html)

*Знаешь, ты последний человек, которого я хотел бы убить* (Е. Галлиади).
*Ты – последний человек, которому бы я дала в долг!* (Л. Матвеева)

P. S. **При логическом выделении местоимения** вполне возможна постановка тире (как в последнем примере): *Ты – последний человек, которого я буду ждать.*
[Все случаи постановки тире](http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200202402) (пункт 3)